# An intuitive meaning of Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to approach for the first time Ito's calculus and SDE, maybe this is a trivial question. If the following is a generic SDE: 
$ dx = \mu(x)dt + \sigma(x)dB_t$
Can i consider the $dx$ as a quantity which describes the changes in $x$ due to a deterministic function $\mu$ plus white noise with $\sigma$ as variance?

and if $x$ were a Stochastic process $X_t$ the previous equation becomes: $dX_t =  \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dB_t$ , is it correct?

Comment: "Can i consider the $dx$ as a quantity which describes the changes in $x$ due to a deterministic function $\mu$ plus white noise with $\sigma$ as variance?" - no.

Comment: @Math1000 can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on the type of model you are dealing with, the underlying distribution of Brownian motion, the way you have expressed it,  and nature of data you are dealing with. For example the OU stochastic differential equation $dT=dS+\gamma (S-T)dt+ \sigma dW$ can be expressed as $$d(T-S)=\gamma (S-T)dt+ \gamma ^2 \sigma dW$$

If $T$ is temperature and $S$ is mean, this form means that if you remove the seasonal component, through calculation of $T-S$, the residual $R=T-S$ will follow a probability distribution with mean $\gamma S$ and variance $\gamma ^2 \sigma ^2$.

Read the works of Gymmerah et al 2021, Primak et al 2001, Dzupire et al, Leobacha and Ngare (2011) for more understanding.